# View datasource returns entries even user has no access to due readers fields

Tags: xpages

I have encountered very strange behaviour I cant explain but I need to. On the Xpage I have embedded views created using view datasources and corresponding repeaters. Now I find out, that view datasource returns all view entries even those user has not access to due access controls (readers fields) . Inside the repeat control I'm getting NotesXSPViewEntry.getDocument() nullPointer error, because NotesXSPViewEntry returns null for getDocument(). How it is that view datasource returns entries for documents I have no access to?? Whats more this app is in production for a year but we discovered this behaviour just recently seems like after upgrade to 9.01FP3 (from 9.01) . Dev server runs on 9.01 without FP and works correctly. Anybody notices such strange behaviour?

**EDIT #1:**
It's single category view and user has no access to any document in the category. Now when I fix the code inside repeate with NotesXSPViewEntry.getDocument()!=null check I can fix the view this way so xpage renders correctly but after any submit it fails with obscure internal error as following. (I tried even with button with empty action only full submit is checked)

```
NotesException: A required argument has not been provided
Location:   
Code Snippet:   

    ... 64 more at com.ibm.xsp.script.WrapperDominoEx$fct_AbstractDominoViewEntry.call(WrapperDominoEx.java:820)    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoViewEntry.getDocument(DominoViewEntry.java:381)   at lotus.domino.local.Database.getDocumentByUNID(Unknown Source)    at lotus.domino.local.Database.NgetDocumentByUNID(Native Method)
Caused by: NotesException: A required argument has not been provided

    ... 48 more at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)   at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:194)   at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:365)   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424) at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435) at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)  at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.binaryop.ASTBinaryRelAnd.interpret(ASTBinaryRelAnd.java:73)  at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.binaryop.ASTBinaryDefaultOp.interpret(ASTBinaryDefaultOp.java:49)    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)  at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) at com.ibm.xsp.script.WrapperDominoEx$fct_AbstractDominoViewEntry.call(WrapperDominoEx.java:1105)null
Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=1, col=19: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesXspViewEntry.getDocument()

    ... 19 more at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:98) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.processDecodes(UIViewRootEx.java:1399)    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._processDecodes(UIViewRootEx.java:1438)   at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:343) at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:166) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processDecodes(UIDataPanelBase.java:331)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processDecodes(UIDataPanelBase.java:331)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processDecodes(UIDataPanelBase.java:331)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processDecodes(UIDataPanelBase.java:331)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.processDecodes(UIDataPanelBase.java:331)   at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1177)  at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataIterator.processDecodes(UIDataIterator.java:780) at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.isRendered(UIDataPanelBase.java:78)    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.isRenderedProp(UIDataPanelBase.java:81)    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:451)   at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)
```

Comment: I think it's more likely to be a category versus rogue null documents. Are you surrounding your getDocument calls with NotesXSPViewEntryHandle.isDocument() checks? Try posting some code.

Comment: see my post edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the View Settings there's a property somewhere that basically says "don't show empty categories".  That's possibly what's happening.  The Readers fields are working but there are pieces of the secured documents inside the view index itself and that's available to more users because of categories.  So in the client you turn on the "don't show empty" option to eliminate that.
I think that would work in the XPages world also but I'm not 100% sure as I've not done a lot of readers fields in XPages.

Comment: Don't show empty categories is the key!!! But something had to change because there was no problem until R9.0.1FP2